# IE8 list item hover affect other list items when sub-menu active

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a main menu using a list. When the user hovers over an item it moves up to indicate the hover to the user all while changing the background color and displaying its sub-menu.

[Link to the website with the issue.](http://box1.thegiant.ca/~sourismini/)

> Add debug=true to the query string if you need firebug.

The issue is in IE8 where if a sub-menu is active and the user hovers over any list item in the main level all of the previous items act like they are being hovered over too. This means that those list items move up but the `background-color` does not change. Depending how the user moves the mouse over the list items, some of the items will even go bellow the start position.

Here is the `SASS` that I converted to `CSS` in order to help understand how I move my menu items like that.

```
#mainmenu ul li:hover,
#mainmenu ul li.active{
    margin-top: -15px
}
```

The only difference in HTML between The sub-menu being active and not is the main level list item has a class `subactive` which is not used by any css and the active sub list item gets a class `active`.

I have a feeling that the issue is somewhere between the `background-color` change and the `margin-top` negative value.

Usually one would expect the elements after to be affected and not the ones before.

Please avoid any `Javascript` fixes please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE8, when you adjust the `margin-top: -15px`, it pushes the UL box top to fit, instead of letting the LI go outside the UL box. So all the other tabs move up to fit the new UL box.

I suggest setting the non-hover LI to `margin-top: 15px` and hover LIs to `margin-top: 0`--reverse it.

```
#mainmenu UL LI
{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#mainmenu UL LI:hover
{
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

(This will still work cross-browser.)

Comment: Thanks that did it for me! I thought of the issue where the UL box top to fit but the IE8 debugger told me otherwise (should not have trusted it that much). Logically it would make all elements move up with it and not just the ones to the left of the hovered element. Thanks again tho.

Comment: Yeah, IE is a mess sometimes. I don't know why it raised some and not others either; maybe some combination of floats in ULs and margins? Browser rendering can get very complicated when you get everything interacting with each other.